# Segmentation Fault happening when trying to pass objects by reference in qt program

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

I am using Qt and have made it so that two `dialogs` appear before my `centralwidget`. Inside my second dialog (`playerInfo`) I created a `QcomboBox` and a `QlineEdit` that takes in an int and a `QString`. I then store those values into my player class. However when I create my `centralwidget` and try to pass the player objects into it, it segfaults.

my main.cpp

```
int main( int argv, char* argc[] ) {
    int numberPlayers = 0;
  QApplication app( argv, argc );
  MainWindow mw;
  numPlayers pPlayers; //first dialog that prompts the user to enter in how many players
   numberPlayers = pPlayers.returnInput();
 playerInfo *pInfo = new playerInfo(numberPlayers, &mw); //user enters in each players info based off number of players
  pInfo->show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

playerInfo Dialog:

```
#include "playerinfo.h"
using namespace std;

playerInfo::playerInfo( int players, MainWindow *mw, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    max_players = players;
    wm = mw; //set wm to point to the address of the mainwindow object

    setFixedSize(400, 400);
    layout= new QVBoxLayout;
    this->setLayout(layout);

    title = new QLabel(tr("Please enter the following information:"));
    layout->addWidget(title);

    lineEdit = new QLineEdit; // create line edit
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    comboBox = new QComboBox; // create combo box and add items to it
    QStringList items = QStringList() << "Hat" << "Car" << "Shoe" << "SpaceShip" << "Basketball" << "Ring";
    comboBox->addItems(items);
    layout->addWidget(comboBox);

    okay = new QPushButton(tr("Accept"));
    layout -> addWidget(okay);
    connect(okay, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(storeInfo()));
}

QString playerInfo::getName() const
{
    return lineEdit->text();
}

int playerInfo::getIndex() const
{
    return comboBox->currentIndex();
}

void playerInfo::storeInfo()
{
    hide();
     index = getIndex();
    name = getName();
    wm->setPlayerData(index, name, pCounter);
    pCounter++;
    if (pCounter != max_players)
    {
         show();
    }
    else if (pCounter == max_players)
    {

        wm->setGUIWidgets(max_players);
        wm->createCentralWidget();
        wm->show();
    }

}
```

My centralwidget.cpp:

```
#include "centralwidget.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

CentralWidget::CentralWidget(Player *players[0], int input): QWidget() {

   for (int i = 0; i < input; i ++) 
   {
      p.append(players[i]); << still segfaulting
    // p[i] = players[i]; // segfaulting here <<<
   }
}
```

I figured out the area that is causing my program to segfault is when i try and pass the addresses of the players I passed in from `playerInfo Dialog` into private variables of the `CentralWidget` class. (`p[i] = players[i];`). Am I passing by reference incorrectly?

If there is anymore information you need (like the header files) please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Edit ::

```
#ifndef CENTRALWIDGET_H
#define CENTRALWIDGET_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include "player.h"

class CentralWidget: public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
   QVector<Player> *p;


  private slots:

 public:
    CentralWidget(Player *players[0], int input);

};

#endif
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>
#include "guiplayervertical.h"
#include "centralwidget.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
  Player *players[4];
  GUIPlayer* guiPlayers[4];
  QWidget *centralWidget;

  int input;
QList<int> index;
QList<QString> name;


  public:
    MainWindow();
    void setPlayerData(int _index, const QString &_name, int i);
    void setGUIWidgets(int input);
    void createCentralWidget();

};
#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
using namespace std;
MainWindow::MainWindow() {
}


void MainWindow::setPlayerData(int _index, const QString &_name, int i)
{
    index.append(_index); // index is a member variable declared somewhere in your mainwindow.h
    name.append(_name); // name is a member variable declared somewhere in your mainwindow.h
    players[i] = new Player(name[i], index[i]);
    guiPlayers[i] = new GUIPlayerVertical( players[i]);
}


void MainWindow::setGUIWidgets(int input)
{
  if (input == 2)
  {
    addDockWidget( Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[0] );
    addDockWidget( Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[1] );
  }
  else if (input == 3)
  {
    addDockWidget( Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[0] );
    addDockWidget( Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[1] );
    addDockWidget( Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[2] );
  }
  else
  {
    addDockWidget( Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[0] );
    addDockWidget( Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[1] );
    addDockWidget( Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[2] );
    addDockWidget( Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, guiPlayers[3] );
  }
}

void MainWindow::createCentralWidget()
{
    centralWidget = new CentralWidget(&players[0], input);

    setCentralWidget( centralWidget );
}
```

Comment: @nik inside the centralwidget constructor

Comment: would it help if i posted the .h files? i didnt want my code to be swarmed with code

Comment: Few points are not clear:1. how are you assigning 'players' passed in constructor?.....2 Are sure the value of 'i' does not exceed the valid memory locations?...Also what is data type of 'p'?

Comment: @nik p is a Player object pointer. Inside the playerInfo dialog you can see that I assign the players from the 0th index to the max number of players. not sure about your first question tho

Comment: Having '0' insize the brackets for players is ignored by the compiler and should be removed. You would get a segfault if 'input' is larger than the size of 'p' or 'players'. You might find it easier wrapping the array in a struct to pass it, or use a std::vector. Can you show the declaration of 'p'.

Comment: Post your header files, mostly centralwidget.h. You say p is a `Player*`, but you seem to be using it as a Player* array (declared `Player* p;` instead of `Player* p[x];`).

Comment: @Vince edited in the header file

Comment: @codah what do you mean by wrapping the array in a struct?

Comment: i can post the gdb results if that would help

Comment: @thuga any chance you can shed some light?

Comment: You are still missing the definition of createCentralWidget(). I think you need to clean out your code and make the smallest snippet possible that shows your issue, if you don't want to follow @codah 's suggestion.

Comment: @Vince I have already removed alot of the code, but i will edit more of it in the next few minutes

Comment: @Vince could you explain codahs suggestion a little bit more?

Comment: @Vince just added and condensed all the code needed to run the program .

Comment: Instead of using Player* player[] and a separate array size as parameter for your constructor, I would strongly suggest you use a std::vector<Player>& players. You'll simplify and make your code more robust. As an alternative, you seem to understand QList, just look into QVector.

Comment: @Vince okay i have just implemented that, but unfortunately that does not solve the seg fault issue. I will edit it into my code now.

Comment: That is not what I meant, and this code should trigger an illegal indirection anyway... In MainWindow, use `QVector<Player*> players` and `CentralWidget(const QVector<Player*>& players)`. Do `players.append( new Player(name[i], index[i]) )` and `new CentralWidget(players)`. When copying, declare p with `QVector<Player*> p`, and replace the whole for loop with `p = players`.

Comment: @vince you just solved my problem ,I can not thank you more than enough. I am still confused how that would cause a seg fault if you could explain that, it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not really dug up the issue you encountered, because your code is too connected, and still misses some information. For example, the user's input is not defined, so if the number of players exceeded 4, it would have *segfaulted*.

However, some of the coding practices in place are worth some refactoring. Since you are having issues with the assignment of `p`, which is copied from a pointer to an array passed as parameter, I suggested you switch to a more flexible and less error-prone method. Using `std::vector` or, in this case, `QVector`, you benefit from a variable-size array, with better memory management, instead of recreating yourself another container, or relying on a fixed-size array.

Start at the member of your class, and declare

```
private:
    QVector<Player*> players;
```

Then, fill your container using

```
players.append( new Player(name[i], index[i]) );
```

When passing the vector as parameter to the constructor of your other class, use a const reference of the same type, this is the equivalent of passing a single pointer, not the whole object

```
CentralWidget(const QVector<Player*>& players);
```

Note that using the container, you do not need to also give the array size separately.
Finally, this simplifies a lot of the remaining changes. You can now pass the whole member as parameter

```
centralWidget = new CentralWidget(players);
```

And simply copy it using

```
p = players;
```

No need for the `for` loop anymore.